# image.src in asp.net always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i have an `image` control whose source can be updated at run time because i am showing employee's picture in it and this was loaded from database as:

```
EmpImage.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

and to update record i need to check image source is empty or not as:

```
 if (EmpImage.Src.Length == 0)
```

or

```
if (EmpImage.Src == "")
```

but it shows me empty all the time...

i read this thread [ASP.NET image src question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569797/asp-net-image-src-question) but here `jquery` is used but I need server side solution

**EDIT:**

i read image from database to image control as:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["Pic"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Pic"];
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    // EmpImage.ImageUrl = base64String;

                    EmpImage.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

                 }
```

where `dt` is `datatable` and i got this from google

i need your help to get out of it.

i am using `asp.net c#`

thanks in advance.

Comment: is base64String contains image data ?

Comment: Please show the code how are you getting base64String .

Comment: please see my edits in question

Comment: Just check I posted one answer instead of Src use ImageUrl it will work

Comment: I got your problem now do one thing EmpImage.Attributes.Add("src","data:image/png;base64," + base64String) it will work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side Image control has [ImageUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is of `String` type, so you can directly use string functions:-

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmpImage.ImageUrl)
{

}
```

**Update:**

As per the exception posted by you, it is sure that you are not using the ASP.NET server side `Image` control i.e. `<asp:Image` but the [html image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage(v=vs.110).aspx) control with `runat="server"` tag. So in this case agian since [Src](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.src(v=vs.110).aspx) property is of type `String`, you can use the same method as:-

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmpImage.Src)
{

}
```

Comment: on imageUrl it shows error that "Error 8 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl' and no extension method 'ImageUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't mention it in my question, you are right i didn't use asp:Image

Comment: @Waqas - Ohk so now is it working? I am not sure if you wanted to check this or not.

Comment: let me check this and then i will be back for update.

Comment: Sir i need to confirm something more, same situation i got in file upload control which is html but applying runat="server" , but this if(File_Upload.PostedFile != null) this allow compiler to enter into if body either file is  selected or not , will you please suggest me any solution about this

Comment: @Waqas - Hey that will return the `HttpPostedFile` object so that condition will never help. Check like this: `File_Upload.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0`

Answer (score 1):

instead of Src use ImageUrl property

```
   if (dt.Rows[0]["Pic"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Pic"];
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    // EmpImage.ImageUrl = base64String;

                    EmpImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;

                 }
```

Comment: i am sorry to say that i didn't mention in my question that i made html image control to asp by using runat="server" , so imageurl does not work in this case.

Comment: Then how are you using .Src property isn't it causing you build error ??

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, whenever you set image source dynamically, you will never get source length/info on page posting. You have to manage some flag using hidden inputs.

Comment: will you please me give example if you have time.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do so. show me your complete requirement, based on that i can give you solution.

Comment: I read image from database and then have to update image, i have scenario 1) update prev image 2) set null image 3) change prev image        for doing this job i need to check this

Answer (score 0):

Set your image object to the following presentation:

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Image id="test" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("Pic")) %>' />
```

**Cs**

```
  public string GetImage(object img)
    {
     string base64String ="";
    if (dt.Rows[0]["Pic"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Pic"];
                        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                     }
       return "data:image/png;base64," + base64String ;
    }
```